# How to call javascript functions from XSLT without using additional libraries etc.?

Tags: javascript, xslt

I must have a return value from javascript function. Is there a way to do this without using additional libraries. What I tried:

```
<xsl:variable name="fieldOf">
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="type">
    <xsl:value-of>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            getTypeFromXSDFile(<xsl:value-of select="$fieldOf"/>)        
        </script>
    </xsl:value-of>
</xsl:variable>
```

So that I can use return value of javascript function.

Thanks

Comment: @savruk: You can call any extension function as long as your XSLT processor implements it or you provide its implementation to the transformation context. In XSLT 1.0, any function call with namespace prefix will be an [extension function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Extension-Functions). How to register an extension function entirely depends on the XSLT processor.

Comment: @savruk: If you provide a description of the function, someone might bring you a pure XSLT implementation.

Comment: @Alejandro With this function I want to get this Xpath query's result from xsd file: 
`xs:schema/xs:element[@name=$fieldNameFromXmlFile]/@type`

This is basicly what I need. I try to do it with dynamic Xpath query as $fieldNameFromXmlFile always change. But it did not work. So I thought maybe if I can call javascript I could get the type.

Comment: @savruk: The expression in your comment should work.

Comment: @Alejandro But when I try to get the type with <xsl:value-of>, it behaves like a string. And just put the "xs:schema/xs:element[@name='sampleField']/@type" to page. It does not get the type of the element

Comment: @savruk: With `<xsl:value-of select="document($schemaURI)/xs:schema/xs:element[@name=$fieldNameFromXmlFile]/@type">` ?

Comment: No change. I tried maybe all possibilities. Well I use concat() to add apostrophe before it comes to value-of. I do not think it has effects on it but maybe.  It perfectly works when I put xpath statically.But not with variable

Comment: @savruk: XPath evaluation is always static...

Comment: Think, I use below code in a for-each element. And in every loop $fieldNameFromXmlFile changes. Does it work? I ask because mine does not work.
<xsl:value-of select="document($schemaURI)/xs:schema/xs:element[@name=$fieldNameFromXmlFile]/@type">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Not in pure XSLT.

Some XSLT processors provide their own way to call Javascript (or other language) functions. For example, all Microsoft XSLT processors provide the **[`<msxsl:script>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256042.aspx)** element.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can only use [XPath functions](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp).